# Ruby on Rails Telegram Notification. Is it secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rubygems, telegram

I'm trying to use tele_notify gem:
[Tele Notify](https://github.com/ppati000/tele_notify)

This Gem use Webhook, so I set it with Telegram:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebHook?url=https://<EXAMPLE.COM>/<TOKEN>
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

Then in Application Controller:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  #IMPORTANT! THESE TWO LINES MUST COME AFTER protect_from_forgery!
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :webhook
  include TeleNotify::Controller

  #other code...
end
```

And finally the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post '/<your token>' => 'application#webhook'
end
```

Is this code secure? Anyone experienced with this gem?

It is a problem to skip authenticity token?

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :webhook
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite secure. Intentionally or not, but you seem to be following [official recommendations](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api):

> If you'd like to make sure that the Webhook request comes from Telegram, we recommend using a secret path in the URL, e.g. `https://www.example.com/<token>`. Since nobody else knows your bot‘s token, you can be pretty sure it’s us.

As for skipping authenticity token check, it *must* be done, because telegram servers have no way of knowing the token. (it is precisely the idea behind the token and the check: remote servers, not knowing the token, can't make requests. But here you *want* them to be able to hit this certain endpoint).